# Merge Razor C# value with string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have some value in meta tag like this

```
<meta property="og:image" content="/Content/images/share-image.jpg"" />
```

The problem is that Facebook wants tag to be like this

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/Content/images/share-image.jpg"" />
```

I know in MVC how to get base URL like this @Request.Url.AbsoluteUri

The problem is when I try something like this in view

```
  <meta property="og:image" content="@Request.Url.AbsoluteUriContent/images/share-image.jpg"" />
```

I got Error, how can i merge string in view with this

```
@Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

and

```
Content/images/share-image.jpg
```

Comment: Try @(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri), note the brackets around the call

Comment: What about something like`content=@Request.Url.AbsoluteUriContent+"/images/share-image.jpg"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using braces around the C# statement:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="@(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)Content/images/share-image.jpg" />
```

This will explicitly tell the Razor parser that the text inside `@()` is C# code.

Comment: I moved the closing paranthesis infront of "Content"

Comment: Thanks @Serv, you beat me to it. ;-)